# Cannot resolve Directory when trying to add audio file to website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add audio to my website but I get the error "Cannot resolve Directory". Ive tried different paths including /../../audiofile.mp3 still nothing

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: show us what exactly you tried and where actually audio file in your pc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I resolved the issue this afternoon. The path I was using was correct. It had to be "../../audiofie.mp3". Now the issue is it just say loading but never plays the file